# In R ,how can i split a long character

Tags: r, split

In R,there is a long character "mr" as blow，how can i split "mr" by number (split into three short strings):

```
mr <- 'total amount 25.36 expense -2 promotion discount-2.56'

# 'total amount 25.36','expense -2','promotion discount-2.56'
```

Comment: what do you mean "split by number" `strsplit(mr, '(?<=\\d) ', perl = TRUE)[[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = mr) %>% 
   separate_rows(col1, sep="(?<=\\d) ") %>%
   separate(col1, into = c("Description", "Amount"),
           sep = "(?<=[a-z])\\s*(?=[-0-9])", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Description        Amount
#   <chr>               <dbl>
#1 total amount        25.4 
#2 expense             -2   
#3 promotion discount  -2.56
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @rawr 's comment,
If you want to have it as a data frame,

```
mr <- 'total amount 25.36 expense -2 promotion discount-2.56'
splt <- strsplit(mr, '(?<=\\d) ', perl = TRUE)[[1]]
df <- data.frame("Desciption" = gsub("[^a-z ]", "", splt),
           "Amount" = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", splt)))
df
          Desciption Amount
1      total amount   25.36
2           expense   -2.00
3 promotion discount  -2.56
```